# jQuery - Selectors for an element with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

on my page I have many `label` tags. Some of them has the `for` attribute. How should be the jQuery's selector of that label's ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HptPm/1/)**

```
$("label[for]")​
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this: `$('label[for]')` if you don't know what is equal to `for`

Answer (score 1):

A selector like this one will be helpful :

```
$('label[for="foo"]').css('color', 'red);
```

EDIT after comment :

To select all labels without knowing the `for` value :

```
$('label[for]').css('color', 'red);
```

Comment: Ok, but the value of the `for` attribute is different of the each label which has it